# Getting _id fields of aggregated records in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES to aggregate results based on a field. Additional to that, I would like to retrieve the _id of the records that went into each aggregated bucket as well. Is it possible ?

For example: for the following query

```js
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genders" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "gender" }
        }
    }
}
```

the response would be something like this

```js
{
    ...

    "aggregations" : {
        "genders" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0, 
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0, 
            "buckets" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : "male",
                    "doc_count" : 14
                },
                {
                    "key" : "female",
                    "doc_count" : 14
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here I want the _id of all the 14 male and 14 female records that make up the aggregation as well.

Why would I need that ?

Say, because I need to some post processing on these records i.e. insert a new field in those records based on their gender. Of course, its not as trivial as that, but my use case is something on that lines.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create nested aggregation something like

```js
{
    "aggs" : {
        "genders" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "gender" }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "ids":{
                "terms" : {"field" : "_uid"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get no id buckets. I think it does not treat _id as a field.

Comment: Looks like you may have to use `_uid` or index `_id` field
Check https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9298

Comment: Great. It works. Please edit your answer so I can accept.

Comment: This is now deprecated:
> Deprecation: Loading the fielddata on the _id field is deprecated and will be removed in future versions. If you require sorting or aggregating on this field you should also include the id in the body of your documents, and map this field as a keyword field that has [doc_values] enabled

Comment: And the we hsould map the ids withe the genders, they are not return on the same array ?